# Nhibernate many-to-many add on both sides

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm creating a many-to-many implementation with Nhibernate. Currently I have the below classes. In both classes I implemented the `AddObjX(Objx obj)` method to add the item to the collection.

```
Obj1
{
  int id;
  Ilist<Obj2> obj2;
}

Obj2
{
  int id;
  Ilist<Obj1> obj1;
}
```

In the mappings I have

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Obj1)
   .Table("Obj1Obj2")
   .ParentKeyColumn("Obj1Id")
   .ChildKeyColumn("Obj2Id")
   .Inverse()
   .Cascade
   .SaveUpdate();

HasManyToMany(x => x.Obj2)
   .Table("Obj1Obj2")
   .ParentKeyColumn("Obj2Id")
   .ChildKeyColumn("Obj1Id")
   .Inverse()
   .Cascade
   .SaveUpdate();
```

When I now say

```
obj1.AddObj2(obj2);
Session.SaveOrUpdate(obj1);
```

I only get an association between obj1 -> obj2. So if I retrieve obj2 there is no obj1 coupled to it. When I retrieve obj1 there is an obj2 coupled to it.

When I do

```
obj1.AddObj2(obj2);
obj2.AddObj1(obj1);
Session.SaveOrUpdate(obj1);
```

I have the object in both scenario's. Is this as designed or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried dropping the `Inverse` from the second HasManyToMany?

AFAIK you should only have one inverse as this instructs NH which side of mapping is responsible for insert.

See this [post by northerdev](http://notherdev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/many-to-many-mapping-inverse.html) also this [follow up post](http://notherdev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/many-to-many-mapping-collection-types.html) .